# How could I call a lighbox from a regular text hyperlink?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using Wordpress with Elementor.

I'd like a certain hyperlink (a regular piece of text from the middle of a regular paragraph) to call a lightbox with an image.

E.g.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> [eiusmod tempor](https://#) incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
> enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco

By clicking on the hyperlink above, it should open a lightbox with an image.

How could I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Easiest way to Use popup Template.

1. First Create a Popup Using Elementor Builder.
2. Trigger it With the hyperlink.

Here you will get details instructions: [Check Here](https://elementor.com/help/how-to-trigger-a-popup-on-a-link-click/)